# Invoke triggersends in ET Via REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send

I have Configured a TriggeredSend under interactions. Here is the path
Triggered Sends > Autoemail

We are unable to initiate an email through REST API from Salesforce. We are testing this in the POSTMAN and receive "404 not found" error.

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:Autoemail/send

Not sure if I am missing somthing here.

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142953/exacttarget-rest-api-using-httpclient-c). Refer to my answer in this question.

Comment: I am following all the steps mentioned. i have also published and also TS email is started. still we see 404 error

Comment: I'm 99.5% certain that this would be related to the credentials that you used when you created the API Integration app. Are you sure that you selected the correct Business Unit and the user account you used has access to the Triggered Send?

Comment: What have you set the app permissions to? Do you have permission to send email and execute interactions?

Comment: Eliot, Thanks for the reply. I have added the App Setup screenshot for your reference

Comment: I still get 404 Not Found.

Comment: Please can you share an example Postman request that you are using? I assume that you are are replacing 'Autoemail' in your endpoint with the numeric External Key of the Triggered Send?

Comment: I have updated the image. please help me where we are missing. i have tested with using both but still see the same error messageDefinitionSends/26582/Send messageDefinitionSends/key:26582/Send

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint that you provided in your question is correct, but this not match the endpoint in your screenshot. Note that `key:` is missing. Without this string, you will receive a 404 error.

The correct endpoint you need to use is:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:26582/send
```